# How to access shared preference between activities in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have two activities **A** and **B**. Activity **A** has a form and by clicking on submit button it saves the form data into shared preference. Activity B has to retrieve data from the shared preferences saved by activity **A**. I went through so many forums and got suggestion to uses `getSharedPreference(Filename,Mode)` instead of `getPreference(Mode)`. But still it does not work. Is there any other method to do this job instead of creating a class in activity **A** specially to extract shared preference values for public use.

Please suggest a perfect solution for this. I even used the mode as WORLD_READABLE.

Comment: please post the code that you are saving your SharedPreferences with.

Comment: Please check my code here - http://pastebin.com/0W64gnEt.  Please search for the word "XYZ12345" in my code where I have written my problem as comment. I would be obliged to get the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the editor is not actually committing changes due to how you are opening your `SharedPreferences`.

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("udata",MODE_WORLD_READABLE).edit();
```

Change `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` to `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` and see if that helps.

Comment: servState = 1;
editor.putInt("AppState", servState);
editor.commit();                                                           I have committed the changes in the above code. Initially I was using the MODE_PRIVATE only but since it din't work I used the MODE_WORLD_READABLE mode. any other suggestion please

Comment: You should debug the commit code, ensure that mPwd.getText().toString() is not returning null, and ensure that the commit is working.

Comment: i have same problem, when i start activity when back onresume() is call " pref.getBoolean(Constant.PREF_KEY, true) " or startactivity(...); finish();

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`.  The JavaDoc is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html

Your other attempts should work, but without seeing the code I'm not sure why it is isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There was some initialization problem. Now I got the solution. Thanks for all your support